# Material UI Autocomplete Dropdown option not working after switching tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, autocomplete, react-state-management

In my new project, I am using material UI autocomplete within tabs, and using `useImmer` hooks for state management. Values in the autocomplete are populated through map function and everything works properly. However, the dropdown functionality is not working after switching the Tabs.

The values are reaching to this component as

```
const Dropdownlist = ({ defaultRates, value, onChange, index }) => {

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...defaultRates}
        size="small"
      inputValue={value}
      value={value}
      autoSelect={true}
      clearOnEscape={true}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      onChange( newValue, index );
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField  {...params} />}
    />
  );
};

export default Dropdownlist;
```

Values of 'defaultRates' was built using

```
const ratings =
Rates.map((charge) => {
    return ({ id: charge.rateid, label: charge.rate });
});

  
const defaultRates = {
  options: ratings,
  getOptionLabel: (option) => option.label,
};
```

Then,

```
const Rates = [
    {
      rateid: 101,
      rate:"10"
    },
    {
      rateid: 102,
      rate:"30"
    },
    {
      rateid: 103,
      rate:"1"
    },
    {
      rateid: 104,
      rate:"2"
    },
];
  
export default Rates;
```

Finally, On Change functionality

```
const onChange = (e,i) => {
    let newState;
  
    if(e)
    {
      const { id, label } = e;

      newState = transactions.map((item, index) => {

      var tds = (label/100)*item.amount;
      
        if (index === i) {  
        return {
          id: item.id,
          transaction: item.transaction,
          amount: item.amount,
          name: item.name,
          type: item.type,
          ts:item.ts,
          tr:label,
          tds: tds,
          error:false,
          };

        } else {
          return item;
        }
  
      });

      
      setTransactions(newState);

    }
  
  }
```

*In the first tab I have many autocomplete dropdown and the selected values are also using in the second tab. If I switch to Tab2 and return back to Tab1, I can see the selected values there. But If I want to change the selected value, nothing happens while clicking the dropdown icon*. Please let me know if anyone ever experienced in this context. Would like to know if I using Material UI autocomplete parameters in the right way?

I have gone through Material UI documentation and Autocomplete params. Please advise if it is a state management issue or Mat UI bug?

Comment: can you add a codesandbox?